# bash-scripting error on Microsoft AppCenter for pre-build script

Tags: bash, visual-studio-app-center

I am having issues with the pre-build script on appcenter. Appcenter uses bash for the pre-build scripts. I want to change "qa.api" to "beta.api" in my api.js file.

I tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "$APPCENTER_BRANCH" != "master" ];
then
    cd App/Services/
    echo "changing QA API to Production API (beta)"
    sed -i 's/qa.api/beta.api/g' Api.js
fi
```

So I simplified it but it still does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd App/Services/
sed -i 's/qa.api/beta.api/g' Api.js`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace `App/Services/` with absolute path?

Comment: Did not work.. ;(

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 0):

sed's `-i` option takes a parameter to indicate what extension to add to the file name when making a backup. Unlike linux versions, on macOS, this extension parameter is required.

Try to provide an empty string here:
`sed -i '' 's/qa.api/beta.api/g' Api.js`